# How do access the content of tk entry fields generated in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Still trying to teach myself GUI development using tkinter, I decided to try to code a simple substitution cipher app as a learning exercise.

At the core of this is the alphabet where each letter in the plaintext is mapped to a fixed letter in the ciphertext alphabet.

I would like to generate the (26 * 2) widgets (one label and one entry box) in a loop.

Whilst I can do this (see example code), I cannot work out how to access the data typed in to the entry field. I have looked at examples where buttons are generated in a loop, and the "command" is linked using a lambda function - but I can't see how to do this with entry fields.

Of course I could do:

```
entryA = tk.Entry(self.input_frame, width=1).grid(row=1, column=0)
entryB = tk.Entry(self.input_frame, width=1).grid(row=1, column=1)
....
entryZ = tk.Entry(self.input_frame, width=1).grid(row=1, column=25)
```

but that seems cumbersome and inelegant.

What I would like to achieve, I guess, is some sort of event which, when the user types a letter into a particular box, the alphabet dictionary gets updated - but how do I know which box they have typed in? I have played around with the "name" field, but got nowhere so far...

Thanks in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title="Sample App", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.title(title)
        self.alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
        # (This will be a dictionary in the real implementation)

        # Create a frame:
        self.input_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="The Alphabet")
        self.input_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.input_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.input_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.draw_alphabet()


    def draw_alphabet(self):
        for i in range(26): # Display each letter and an entry box to enter letter
            tk.Label(self.input_frame,
                    text=self.alphabet[i]
                    ).grid(row=0, column=i)
            tk.Entry(self.input_frame,
                 width = 1,
                 name = f"letter{i}").grid(row=1, column=i)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to generate the (26 * 2) widgets (one label and one entry box) in a loop. Whilst I can do this (see example code), I cannot work out how to access the data typed in to the entry field.

Tkinter objects are no different than any other python objects. You can store them in a list and then iterate over the list to access the objects.

```
def draw_alphabet():
    self.entries = []

    for i in range(26):
        ...
        entry = tk.Entry(self, input_frame, width=1, name=f"letter{i}")
        entry.grid(row=1, column=i)
        self.entries.append(entry)

def print_values():
    for entry in self.entries:
        print(entry.get())
```

> how do I know which box they have typed in?

You can call `focus_get()` on any widget to get the widget that has the keyboard focus.

Or, if you have set up a binding to call a function when the user types something, you could pass in the index into the function. The correct solution depends on how you are calling that function.

Comment: Oh Wow! I had no idea it was that simple -I have been trying all sorts of convoluted things! Many, many thanks Bryan!

Comment: One more question if I may: - focus_get() returns something like .!labelframe.letter5. How can I extract just the "letter5" part as I would like to use these as keys to my dictionary (and don't want it cluttered with the .!labelframe bit if I can avoid it). that way I can have a FoucusOut event updating the dictionary value for that key. I thought it would be simple - but so far I haven't cracked it. (there doesn't appear to be a __name_ attribute and _nametowidget seems to return the same value as above).

Comment: At the moment I have it working by doing a rather clunky:  letter=repr(event.widget); letter = letter[-1] which works, but feels like a kludge. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @ArthurDent: that's not something that can be answered in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

With enormous thanks to the ever helpful @Bryan Oakley, I now have this working - see below (obviously not the whole implementation, but the bit I needed help with).

My follow-up question relates to the "handleOut" method which deals with updating the dictionary once the user has typed a letter into the field.

In particular, obtaining the letter in question by means of `letter =str(event.widget); letter = letter[-1]`
feels like a bit of a kludge.

If there is a neater way to do this (or anything else in my not-very-good code) please do let me know. This is a learning exercise for me.

With thanks:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title="Sample App", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.title(title)
        self.alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
        self.alphabet_dict = {'A':"*", 'B':"*", 'C':"*", 'D':"*", 'E':"*", 'F':"*", 'G':"*", 'H':"*", 'I':"*", 'J':"*", 'K':"*", 'L':"*", 'M':"*", 'N':"*", 'O':"*", 'P':"*", 'Q':"*", 'R':"*", 'S':"*", 'T':"*", 'U':"*", 'V':"*", 'W':"*", 'X':"*", 'Y':"*", 'Z':"*"}

        # Create a frame:
        self.input_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="The Alphabet")
        self.input_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.input_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.input_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.draw_alphabet()

    def draw_alphabet(self):
        self.entries = []
        for i in range(26): # Display each letter and an entry box to enter letter
            tk.Label(self.input_frame,
                    text=self.alphabet[i]
                    ).grid(row=0, column=i)
            entry = tk.Entry(self.input_frame, width=1, name=f"letter{self.alphabet[i]}")
            entry.insert(0,self.alphabet_dict[self.alphabet[i]])
            entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.handleIN)
            entry.bind("<FocusOut>", self.handleOut)
            entry.grid(row=1, column=i)
            self.entries.append(entry)

    def print_values(self):
        for entry in self.entries:
            print(entry, entry.get())

    def handleIN(self,event):
        event.widget.delete(0, tk.END)

    def handleOut(self, event):
        typed = event.widget.get()
        if typed.isalpha() and len(typed)==1:
            typed = typed.upper()
        else:
            typed = "*"
        event.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
        event.widget.insert(0, typed)
        letter = str(event.widget)
        letter = letter[-1]
        print(f"Letter {letter} will now be represented by {typed} in the alphabet.")
        self.alphabet_dict[letter] = typed
        #print("focus =", event.widget.focus_get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
     App().mainloop()
```